# How to rebase onto topic branch without getting topic commits in master branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a fairly standard use case where I will create a topic branch off of my main branch (master), and down the road, I would like to get changes into my topic branch that have been introduced into master since I created the topic branch to make sure I have the most current code. I don't like merge commits in my topic branch, so I prefer to rebase commits from master onto the topic branch without having the changes from my topic branch put into master. Is there a way to get changes from master into topic branch with rebase without having the commits from topic applied to master as well? Or is merge my only option for that?

Thanks.

Comment: That's what rebase does.

Comment: This might help. Keep in mind that rebasing requires forced updates from any other developers. http://infinitemonkeys.influitive.com/a-simple-explanation-for-git-rebase/

Comment: So it seems that my only options to get changes just from master into the topic branch are to merge or cherry-pick.

Comment: You haven't explained very well why you think that, so we can't really help further.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear - I want to get commits from the main branch into my topic branch that have been committed to the main branch since I first created my topic branch cleanly, so that I don't have to create a merge commit each time and so that the history is intact.

Comment: Your goal is clear. Why you think rebase doesn't achieve the goal is not.

Comment: Because, as I explained above, I don't want the commits from my topic branch added to my main branch when I'm grabbing commits from the main branch, and rebase does exactly that. I want to wait until I'm done with the work in my topic branch before moving those commits into the main branch.

Comment: That. Does. Not. Happen. The master branch is not modified by rebasing a topic branch. Look at torek's answer below. The master branch is not modified.

Comment: So I'm imagining things when I do "git rebase topic" from master and commits from my topic branch now show up in master?

Comment: Yeah, that would be backwards. Check out your topic branch and run `git rebase master`.

Comment: According to [this page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) in the Pro Git book, that's not how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordinary `rebase` *can* do the trick.  If you're the only developer of the topic branch, and you use just one system to do the development (and a central server for backup), it's pretty easy to simply force-push your rebased topic branch as you go.

For instance, yesterday you had:

```
        F - G   <-- topic
      /
... E - H - I   <-- master
```

Today you decided that commit `I` on master was very `I`mportant to your topic and you want `topic` rebased onto master, so (while on branch `topic`) you run:

```
git rebase master
```

which does this:

```
        F - G   [abandoned]
      /
... E - H - I   <-- master
             \
              F' - G'   <-- topic
```

in your own repository.  (Commits `F'` and `G'` are "copies" of the original `F` and `G`, which only really starts to matter in the "fork point" stuff below.)  You must then force-push `topic` if you're copying it somewhere else, which adds a few risks:

- what if someone else is developing on their copy of `topic`?
- worse, what if someone else is also doing this rebase and has their own additional commit `J` and has already done a force-push so that the centralized backed-up server has:

  ```
  ... E - H - I   <-- master
               \
                F' - G' - J   <-- topic
  ```

Well, **if there is no "someone else"**, neither of those can possibly have occurred and you're fine.

#### But what if there *is* someone else?

You'll need an alternative.  You can of course use merges or cherry-picking.  But you can still use rebase, *provided* you and all the "someone else"s agree that this can happen.  And then you need (or at least strongly want) some of the newer git tools:

- `--fork-point`
- `--force-with-lease`

What `--fork-point` does is smarten up `git rebase` so that you can take a moved topic branch, and use your own reflogs to figure out which commits were copied, so that you can rebase just your own work and not someone else's.  It's not perfect but it's a big assist here.

What `--force-with-lease` does is perhaps the most important.  Suppose you're doing the `rebase` above, and someone else has done the rebase and added a new commit `J`.  When you go to `git push` the rebased `topic`, you tell your git and the central-server git that you'd like to make `topic` point to commit `G'` on the server, *but only if it currently points to commit `G` on the server*.  In this case, the "someone else" beat you to the force-with-lease push, so that on the server, `topic` now points to commit `J`.  This makes your force-with-lease push fail, and you can then run `git fetch` and figure out what happened and coordinate your own work accordingly.

(Remember that each of these single uppercase letters stands for some unique 40-character SHA-1.  If you have a new commit atop your copied `F'` and `G'` you can still assume that the server uses the ID you have in your commit `G`, and it all works: either the server really does have that ID, because no one else has pushed, or it does not, because someone else has pushed.  Those are the only two server-side possibilities.  You do have to be quite careful, though, because after your `git fetch` yor `origin/topic` now points to commit `J` too.)